# Why the pow function when used in printf() produce arbitrary results?

Tags: c, pow

I have this code in C-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%d",(12345/pow(10,3)));
}
```

It outputs any arbitrary value,why is it not outputting 12?
Isn't the above code equivalent to-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int i=12345/pow(10,3);
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

It outputs 12,
Why the two codes outputting different values?Can someone please explain.

Comment: Truly an arbitrary value or consistently a value other than 12 with a specific value that is reproducible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pow` returns a `double`, therefore causing undefined behavior because you pass it to a format string expecting an `int`, since `typeof(int / double) == double`.

Try

```
printf("%lf\n", 12345 / pow(10, 3));
```

or use an explicit cast, like

```
printf("%d\n", 12345 / (int) pow(10, 3));
```

Answer (score 2):

The result of `pow` is type `double`, so the whole expression `12345/pow(10,2)` has type `double`.  Unfortunately, you're trying to print that double value with the `%d` conversion specifier, which expects an `int` value.

If you want an integer output, do the following:

```
printf( "%d", (int)(12345/pow(10,3)));
```

Otherwise, print it as a double:

```
printf( "%f", 12345/pow(10,3));
```

Answer (score 0):

when assiging `12345/pow(10,3)` to an int, the result is converted to int.

When passing `12345/pow(10,3)` to `printf` a double is pushed onto the stack, but `printf` expects an int as per your format specification.

Answer (score -1):

```
printf( "%g", 12345/pow(10,3));
```

this may solve your problem

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["How do I write a good answer??"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). You might also want to learn about ["Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples"] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The question asks "why". Your answer doesn't answer the question.